# Impute missing values for missing dates

Tags: r, date, imputation

Imagine I have the following two data frames:

```
> sp
        date value
1 2004-08-20     1
2 2004-08-23     2
3 2004-08-24     4
4 2004-08-25     5
5 2004-08-26    10
6 2004-08-27    11

> other
        date value
1 2004-08-20     2
2 2004-08-23     4
3 2004-08-24     5
4 2004-08-25    10
5 2004-08-27    11
```

where the first columns represents the dates and the second the values for each day. The matrix of reference is `sp` and I want to impute to the matrix other the missing dates and values with respect to `sp`.  For instance, in this case I miss the date `"2004-08-26"` in the matrix `other`. I should add to the matrix other a new row, with the date `"2004-08-26"` and the value which is given by the mean of the values at `"2004-08-25"` and `"2004-08-27"`.

Could anyone suggest me how I can do it?

### Data

```
sp <- data.frame(date=c("2004-08-20", "2004-08-23", "2004-08-24", "2004-08-25",
                        "2004-08-26", "2004-08-27"), value=c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11))

other <- data.frame(date=c("2004-08-20", "2004-08-23", "2004-08-24", "2004-08-25",
                           "2004-08-27"), value=c(2, 4, 5, 10, 11))
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to add dates from `sp` that are missing in `other`.

You can `merge` `other` with just the `date` column of `sp`. Note, that by default from one-column data frames (and matrices) dimensions are dropped, so we need `drop=FALSE`.

The resulting `NA` can be e.g. linearly interpolated using `approx`, which gives the desired mean.

```
other2 <- merge(other, sp[, 'date', drop=FALSE], all=TRUE) |>
  transform(value=approx(value, xout=seq_along(value))$y)
other2
#         date value
# 1 2004-08-20   2.0
# 2 2004-08-23   4.0
# 3 2004-08-24   5.0
# 4 2004-08-25  10.0
# 5 2004-08-26  10.5  ## interpolated
# 6 2004-08-27  11.0
```

**Note:** For **R < 4.1**, do:

```
transform(merge(other, sp[, "date", drop = FALSE], all = TRUE), 
          value = approx(value, xout = seq_along(value))$y)
#         date value
# 1 2004-08-20   2.0
# 2 2004-08-23   4.0
# 3 2004-08-24   5.0
# 4 2004-08-25  10.0
# 5 2004-08-26  10.5  ## interpolated
# 6 2004-08-27  11.0
```

Comment: Thank you! In overall this solution works for me. But when I am trying to run the whole line, R returns the following error: Error: unexpected '>' in "merge(other, sp[, 'date', drop=FALSE], all=TRUE) |>"                                                       I am also not sure why you use $y? Thank you.

Comment: @Lyuba **1.** Update your R or use the code in the note I just added to my answer. **2.** `approx` yields `x` and `y` coordinates, as it's often used in `plot` functions to interpolate lines. In this case we only want `y`, (`x` is just the sequence of indices, try `approx(other$value, xout = seq_along(other$value))` to see for yourself).

Answer (score 2):

An option using `zoo::na.approx` :

```
library(dplyr)

sp %>%
  select(date) %>%
  left_join(other, by = 'date') %>%
  mutate(value = zoo::na.approx(value))

#        date value
#1 2004-08-20   2.0
#2 2004-08-23   4.0
#3 2004-08-24   5.0
#4 2004-08-25  10.0
#5 2004-08-26  10.5
#6 2004-08-27  11.0
```